# SVG: text in viewBox where the width is really small (1 unit wide)

Tags: css, svg

I have the following SVG

```
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg">
...
</svg>
```

I want now to position text at (0.2, 100). If I just add `<text x="0.2" y="20">This text does not provide good UX</text>`, I'll get a vertical black thin line.

It seems that my only option is to `scale()` the text, for example by doing  Are there ways to avoid scaling, but rather set some other properties on the `<text>` element?

Inserting `<text x="0.2" y="20" transform="scale(0.001, 1)">Hello</text>`

As an example:

```
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg">
    <rect x="0.2" y="20" fill="black" height="10" width="0.1"></rect>
    <text x="0.2" y="20" transform="scale(0.001, 1)">Hello</text>
</svg>
```

will give me the text and the rect on wildly different locations, due to the scaling moving the origin of the `<text>` element. Instead of scaling and moving it back, I was wondering: is there a standard solution for this?

TL;DR: I want to have `<text>` elements that display nicely regardless (but with awareness of, if needed) the dimensions of the `viewBox`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative - use textLength and lengthAdjust - while it makes the text readable, it's a bit pixelated on Chrome.

```
<svg width="1200" height="1200" viewBox="0 0 1 1200" preserveAspectRatio="none" id="svg">
    <text x="0.2" y="20" textLength="0.05" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Hello</text>
</svg>
```